# how to deal with expired access token in log in with facebook api php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

How would I determine if the access token is already expired? Last day, i was able to display the information based on the codes below but when i checked it on the following day, it will not redirect to facebook. Is it because of access token? Pls Help. Thank you

```
  // Get User ID
  Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
  Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
  $user = $facebook->getUser();
  $token = $facebook->getAcessToken();

 if ($user) {
try {

  $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
   $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends'); 
   } 
  catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
       error_log($e);
         $user = null;
     } 
   }


 if ($user) {
   $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
   'next'=>'http://localhost/fb/php/examples/logout.php'
  ));
}   else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email,read_stream'));
 }

<?php if ($user): ?>

  <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
<?php else: ?>
  <div>

    <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>

?></pre>

  <?php echo $user; ?>
       <pre>
  <?php 
       print_r($user_profile); 

  ?><pre>
    <pre>
    <?php 

   echo "=== LIST OF FRIENDS ===";

   echo "<br/>";
    $total_friends = count($friends['data']);

    echo 'Total friends: '.$total_friends.'.<br />';
     $start = 0;
    echo '<br />';
    while ($start < $total_friends) {

    echo $friends['data'][$start]['name'];
    ?>
   <?php 
       <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/picture"/> <?php echo $value["data"][$start]   ['name']; ?>
    <?php
    echo '<br />';
    $start++;} 
   ?></pre>


<?php else: ?>
  <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
<?php endif ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it worked yesterday and not today. Since as per the code when

```
$facebook->getUser();
```

does not return any user it will just make the login link and on clicking the login it should take you to the facebook login page.

However in your code you are missing something i.e. redirect_uri so before calling the getLoginUrl you should pass the param as

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream',
  'redirect_uri' => 'page after login' // make sure this is full URL
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Now on the top as you have you can set the access token as below for further call

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$token = $facebook->getAcessToken();
$facebook->setAcessToken($token);
```

Also make sure CURL is enabled before doing any API call with the SDK

Comment: `getLoginUrl` will use the current address automatically when no `redirect_uri` value is given explicitly.

Comment: And that `getAcessToken`/`setAcessToken` stuff is unnecessary as well – `getUser` will automatically populate the access token _if_ it recognizes a logged-in user.